# Too cumbersome change div widths with Javascript on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is re-sizing DIVs on window-resize with Javascript too heavy for most browsers/computers? I'm doing this, because just setting widths in percentages only works in relation to the parent element. I can't seem to make it a percentage of the body, without regard to other parent elements between (on the DOM tree) the elements I would like to resize and the body.

```
function resize_columns() {
  var d = getWindowSize();
  var body_width = d.x;
  var fch_width = body_width * .15;
  var pnh_width = body_width * .25;
  $('.for_customer_div').css('width', fch_width + 'px');
  $('.for_customer_header').css('width', fch_width + 'px');
  $('.project_name_header, .project_name_div').css('width', pnh_width + 'px');
  $('.line_item_div').css('width', pnh_width + 'px');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  resize_columns();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    resize_columns();
  }
});

function getWindowSize() {
  var w = window,
  d = document,
  e = d.documentElement,
  g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
  x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
  y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
  var dimensions = {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
```

Comment: Yes, doing it on every "resize" event is very expensive. It'd be better to have the resize changes only be made at some maximum rate, perhaps only once every quarter second or so. It depends on how much of the DOM you want to change.  Browsers fire many, many "resize" events while the mouse is being dragged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding something like this in your code:

```
function throttle (func, wait) {
    var throttling = false;
    return function(){
        if ( !throttling ){
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            throttling = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                throttling = false;
            }, wait);            
        }
    };
}
```

And then call:

```
window.onresize = throttle(function() {
    resize_columns();
}, 20);
```

This will limit the number number of times `resize_columns` will be called to a maximum of once every 20 milliseconds.

**Explanation:**

The throttle function accepts two parameters: the function you want to execute, and a timeout duration. It then returns a new function with a reference to the `throttling` variable, which acts as a flag. So, as far as `onresize` is concerned, `throttle` just looks like the inner function it returns. Every time that function is executed, it says "is `throttling` set to `false`?". And if it is, it goes ahead and executes your function. Then it sets `throttling` to `true` and creates a `setTimeout` that will wait x number of milliseconds before it sets `throttling` back to `false`. If it gets executed and `throttling` is set to `true`, it doesn't do anything.

So the basic effect is that, at most, your function can only be executed once in a given time window. So you're just rate-limiting.

I know that might not be a great explanation, but I think a full-blown overview of closures would be biting off a little more than I'm willing to chew this morning.

Comment: thank you for posting this; do you think you can explain a little bit how it works?

Comment: i think that is actually a pretty good explanation for a saturday morning. and the code works pretty brilliantly as well. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can cap the maximum rate at which you resize with something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(minTime) {
  var lastResize = 0;
  return function(event) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if (now - lastResize > minTime) {
      lastResize = now;
      resize_columns();
    }
  };
}( 250 )); // 250 millisecond minimum interval between resize changes
```

Comment: every time  new a '''Date''' seems also a heavy job

Comment: @TorrentLee well that's sort-of true, but it's not anywhere close to as much work as a re-render pass.  An alternative would be the answer kennis gives, but whether the trade-off of fewer `gettimeofday()` calls for the event management work is good or bad would be pretty hard to measure.

Comment: thanks for this. what does `event` refer to here? how is it used?

Comment: @thomas oh sorry; that's just the `event` object that jQuery passes to the event handler. Note that there are two functions: the actual event handler, returned from an outer function that sets up the closure with the "lastResize" variable.  The outer function is called to create the actual handler, and then that's passed to jQuery as the handler for the "resize" event.

Comment: okay. i will look into how expensive date creation is, but i think this is pretty nice. thank you!

Comment: @thomas I suspect that the overhead of getting the time from the underlying OS is a matter of a few microseconds on modern hardware.

Comment: I set up a test case on jsPerf to check this approach against mine, just out of pure curiosity. Pretty interesting results: http://jsperf.com/throttle-with-settimeout-vs-date. I wouldn't have expected nearly as much variation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this! I am surprised as well. I will definitely implement the `date()` idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When I've had problems like this I've made the elements that should be a percentage of the body size children of the body, and positioned them absolutely to be within the parent elements where I wanted them to be. Admittedly, it calls for a lot more work to get all the pieces in the right places, but probably not as much as actively resizing.