# what is apply doing here?

Tags: javascript

What specifcially does `func.apply(this, arguments);` do in this code? I can see that it will not work to resize the elements dynamically without the `apply`, however, it seems as though nothing further is done with `this` or `arguments` after `apply` is used.

```
function throttle (func, wait) {
    var throttling = false;
    return function(){
        if (!throttling){
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            throttling = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                throttling = false;
            }, wait);            
        }
    };
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axugek/1/edit)

Comment: It's doing what `.apply` always does. Just because `this` and the passed arguments aren't used here, doesn't mean they're not used in the `func` code.

Comment: Do you have the code for function `func`?

Comment: @bfavaretto it's it `resize_columns()` in the jsbin link.

Comment: @Dre Why did you add the jQuery tag?

Comment: @thomas: `throttle` is meant to be generic, so that if you pass a function that anticipates arguments or an expected value of `this`, the returned function will be sure to pass those values on when invoking the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) allows you to set the `this` and `arguments` values for a method call (and calls it immediately).  That allows you to use the same `this` inside of `func` that is used in the caller of `func.apply`.  Ordinarily, `this` inside of `func` would be something else (perhaps `window` if it's a global function).

Additionally, `.apply` lets you set the arguments with an array, so you don't have to know the argument list ahead of time.

EDIT: in this specific case (the jsbin) it's not needed since `func` never uses `this` or has any arguments.  You can just use `func()`.

Comment: I believe he knows what `apply` does. he's asking why does it being used **here**, and I think there's no reason for that.

Comment: @gdoron it's hard to say; depends on what `func` is (and what `this` usually is inside of `func`) as well as how the returned function is called.

Comment: In the jsbin, I don't see where `this` is being used or why its removal would break anything. `resize_columns()` (what `func` refers to) takes not arguments. Thank you.

Comment: @thomas if you just use `func()` it works .. how did you come up with that code originally?

Comment: This was a function made for me ages ago on SO, but as I've been starting to try to understand closures, I dug it up to see if I could understand it better now. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11485079/1252748) I was just looking for further explanation. Or maybe differently worded so that I could try to understand it from another angle.

Comment: You're right. You can just call `func()`. I guess apply was applied in case further functionality needed eventually to be added to it. Thanks so much. Is that typical to call a function when apply when simply calling it by its name would suffice?

Comment: @thomas no, I wouldn't use `.apply` (or anything) that's not necessary.  It just leads to confusion (like this)

Answer (score 1):

The throttle() function is returning an anonymous function. So the apply allows anonymous function to call itself again and pass the original arguments into it.

So the code is essentially checking if it's throttling or not, if not then set throttling to true and when the timeout is over, set throttle to false.

Comment: This is the right answer. To expand on what the code does, it ensures that it doesn't try to resize every time a window.resize event is posted (which would result in slow downs). Instead, it waits to see if n ms has passed since the last resize event to attempt to deduce if the user has stopped resizing the window. The throttle code seems to have been written independently of the resize code as the code example in the original question does not need any arguments to "survive" the iterations.

Comment: @chris-mv: Sort of. The anonymous function never calls itself. It calls the original function that was passed to throttle. That may be what was meant.